# running Apache + Bottle + Python

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle

I'm trying to run Bottle.py with Apache and mod_wsgi.

I'm running it on windows, using a xampp. python v2.7

My Apache config in httpd:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / C:\xampp\htdocs\GetXPathsProject\app.wsgi
    <Directory C:\xampp\htdocs\GetXPathsProject>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My app.wsgi code:

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import bottle
application = bottle.default_app()
```

My hello.py:

```
from bottle import route
@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

When I go to `localhost/hello` I get a 404 error.
I don't have any other errors on the Apache log file, probably missing something basic.

Comment: Stuck with the same issue =\

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no connecting point from your **wsgi** file to your **hello.py** file. 
 
Put the content in your **hello.py** into the **app.wsgi** and restart your web server. 
That should resolve the problem. 
 
To make your application modular such that you can put the code into various files, check out Bottle's equivalent of Blueprints (used by Flask framework)

Answer (score 5):

Or Duan's comments were a good starting point for me to separate the app.wsgi and the application python file. But they were a little cryptic for me to understand. After messing around for a couple of hours, here is what worked for me: 
[*BTW, I am working on OSX. Please adjust the paths, user, group according to your operating system*]

**/Library/WebServer/Documents/hello_app/app.wsgi:**

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, "/Library/WebServer/Documents/hello_app")

import bottle
import hello
application = bottle.default_app()
```

**/Library/WebServer/Documents/hello_app/hello.py:**

```
from bottle import route

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

**/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName xyz.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess hello_app user=_www group=_www processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias /v1 /Library/WebServer/Documents/hello_app/app.wsgi

    <Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/hello_app>
        WSGIProcessGroup hello_app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart your apache server.

[image: Check the app in the web browser]

Answer (score 2):

I don't see your hello.py referenced anywhere.

You should just put the contents of hello.py (the `route`) into app.wsgi.

Comment: hey, its sound logical, but can you show the code that i need to add?

Comment: Sure, I'm traveling so on my mobile now; will post code when I get back to a computer. But basically it's just both of your files combined into one. If you don't want to wait for me to get back to a laptop just try it. :)

Comment: well i tried and could not make it work with apache, but now i managed to run it without apache, just used the run() command when apache is off, and still, i'll be happier if i'll be able to make it work with apache

Comment: Okay, looks like you took my suggestion (from another answer) and got it working, so I won't post any code now. Happy to hear you're all set.

Comment: There is no need to put the contents of hello.py into app.wsgi. Please check my answer on how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

i'm adding my conclusion for people who will have the same problem as i did:
like Kneel-Before-ZOD and ron.rothman, i had to write my code in the WSGI file since python is running the code from there, BUT if you want to get your own py files you have to IMPORT them from the WSGI files like that:

```
from hello import application
```

the "hello" is the python  FILE NAME and the "application" is the like you should write in you py file and NOT in wsgi:

```
application = bottle.default_app()
```

also had to restart apache every time i made a change(and i didn't know that - that why its made me crazy). 
tnx for the guys who helped me.
GooLuck.

Comment: Just a tip: if you use `bottle.run(reloader=True)` then you won't have to restart apache every time you make a change.

Comment: unfortunately you cant use run with apache :(