# How to configure apache server to host bottle python app via mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, httpd.conf, bottle

For background, I am really new to setting up servers via ssh and the command line so please excuse my inexperience.

I am trying to build a basic app using the bottle (bottlepy) micro framework, I want to host the app using httpd apache server running on centOS 6.6

So far I have been able to get httpd to serve a basic index.html file from the /var/www/html directory. So the apache server is confirmed up and running.

Where I am stuck is how to serve the bottle app with httpd. I read the deployment documentation on the bottlepy site but they skip over specific details. I have tried a few permutations based off other docs I have found, but nothing has worked so I am looking for some really explicit suggestions on what to do here.

At a high level I understand that what has to happen is:

1. alter the httpd configuration so that it loads the app.wsgi file
2. write an app.wsgi file that loads the python application file app.py

First off, is that correct? Or does the app.wsgi file "replace" the app.py file? As in do I just change the file extension and drop into the /var/www directory? That doesn't seem right, but what do I know.

So my three questions are as follows:

1. httpd config:

   - Where *exactly do I put the virtualhost configuration for httpd at?
   - Does it go inside the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file, and if so, where at in the file does it go?
   - Or does it go in its own file, and if so, where do I put that file, what should I name it, and how will httpd know to read it?

This is the config info I have, based off the bottle docs (server is apache 2.2):

```
<VirtualHost *>
   ServerName test_server

   WSGIDaemonProcess app.wsgi user=www-data group=www-data processes=1 threads=5
   WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/my_app/app.wsgi

   <Directory /var/www/my_app>
       WSGIProcessGroup app.wsgi
       WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2. app.wsgi file:

   - What should this file contain to get it to load my python app.py file?
3. app.py file:

   - Where do I put my python app.py file? Or is this explicitly defined in the app.wsgi file so it can be put anywhere?
   - How do I make sure the python code is actually executed and not just read as a text file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678037/running-apache-bottle-python?rq=1). I tried the @MuraliPaluru's answer and it worked for me perfectly. Don't be afraid to check apache's statuslogs if things don't work! :)